# How to get kernel modules archive in buildroot?

Tags: kernel-module, buildroot

When I update the kernel in some board I need to replace modules, kernel image and dtb but buildroot does not provide modules archive.

I need to get kernel modules archive (like module.tar.gz) in output/image folder?

I can extract rootfs and compress /lib/modules/module_folder but it's ugly...

Thanks

Comment: http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.pdf See chapter 17.18.

Answer (score 3):

Buildroot [does not generate packages](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#faq-no-binary-packages), therefore there is no such thing as an archive of kernel modules. If you have a valid use case for packaging kernel modules instead of a full root filesystem, it is something that can be discussed on IRC or the mailing list. However, all use cases we have encountered until now are probably better served with separate Buildroot configurations.